# Increase Z-Index

Tags: javascript, jquery, counter, z-index

I'm trying to find a way to increase Z-Index by 1 on image each time the user hover on title. See website here: https://thellendfortin.webflow.io/

There's sometimes a bug when hovering over a lot of titles quickly. Ideally, the Z-Index would increase +1 each time we hover. Is there a way to achieve that?

Thanks!

```
$('.project-title').on('mouseover',function() {
    $(this).find('.image-thumbnail').css({
    'z-index':'910',
});

$('.project-title').on('mouseout',function() {
      $(this).find('.image-thumbnail').css({
    'z-index':'905',
});
```

Comment: You can do this with css only, no need for Js at all

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript i would use 'https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_zindex.asp' property to set the z-index, but honesly i thing this is more a css thing and there shouldn't be any eventlisteners at all.
[http://zomigi.com/blog/css3-transitions-and-z-index/#:~:text=CSS3%20transitions%20and%20z-index%20You%20can%20apply%20CSS3,browser%20has%20to%20keep%20z-index%20in%20whole%20numbers](http://zomigi.com/blog/css3-transitions-and-z-index/#:%7E:text=CSS3%20transitions%20and%20z-index%20You%20can%20apply%20CSS3,browser%20has%20to%20keep%20z-index%20in%20whole%20numbers).